# How to find the most frequent words in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, cpu-word, frequency, numerical, alphabetical

I am trying to find most frequent words in a text file in alphabetical order in this different program.

For example, the word: "that" is the most frequent word in the text file. So, it should be printed first: "that #"

It needs to be in this type of format as the program and as the answer below:

```
d = dict()

def counter_one():
    d = dict()
    word_file = open('gg.txt')
    for line in word_file:
        word = line.strip().lower()
        d = counter_two(word, d)
    return d

def counter_two(word, d):
    d = dict()
    word_file = open('gg.txt')
    for line in word_file:
        if word not in d:
            d[word] = 1
        else:
            d[word] + 1
    return d

def diction(d):
    for key, val in d.iteritems():
        print key, val

counter_one()
diction(d)
```

It should run something like this in the shell:

```
>>>
Words in text: ###
Frequent Words: ###
that 11
the 11
we 10
which 10
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to get frequency counts is to use the [Counter class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) in the builtin collections module. It allows you to pass in a list of words and it will automatically count them all and map each word to its frequency.

```
from collections import Counter
frequencies = Counter()
with open('gg.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    frequencies.update(line.lower().split())
```

I used the `lower()` function to avoid counting "the" and "The" separately.

Then you can output them in frequency order with `frequencies.most_common()` or `frequencies.most_common(n)` if you only want the top `n`.

If you want to sort the resulting list by frequencies and then alphabetically for elements with the same frequencies, you can use the [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin function with a `key` argument of `lambda (x,y): (y,x)`. So, your final code to do this would be:

```
from collections import Counter
frequencies = Counter()
with open('gg.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    frequencies.update(line.lower().split())
most_frequent = sorted(frequencies.most_common(4), key=lambda (x,y): (y,x))
for (word, count) in most_frequent:
  print word, count
```

Then the output will be

```
that 11
the 11
we 10
which 10
```

Comment: If you're using Python 3 the lambda should be changed to `key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15712231/2393963))

Answer (score 2):

You can do this simpler using collection's `Counter`. First, count the words, then sort by the number of appearances of each word AND the word itself:

```
from collections import Counter

# Load the file and extract the words
lines = open("gettysburg_address.txt").readlines()
words = [ w for l in lines for w in l.rstrip().split() ]
print 'Words in text:', len(words)

# Use counter to get the counts
counts = Counter( words )

# Sort the (word, count) tuples by the count, then the word itself,
# and output the k most frequent
k = 4
print 'Frequent words:'
for w, c in sorted(counts.most_common(k), key=lambda (w, c): (c, w), reverse=True):
    print '%s %s' % (w, c)
```

Output:

```
Words in text: 278
Frequent words:
that 13
the 9
we 8
to 8
```

Comment: You can try running it as is yourself! I was trying to give you an alternative solution for solving this problem that is more concise.

Comment: I know and I appreciate that, but it has to be formatted a certain way like my code is.

Comment: Can you modify your question to specify that format? Or am I missing something?

Comment: And it shouldn't be printing out the way you have it. It should be printed vertically like I have it in my question.

Comment: That is what I want it to happen, but I do need it to print out all the words, though. Is there any way you could add something into my code to make it print that way? I don't use the from and import functions. That's a bit too advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you keep re-opening the file and creating new dictionaries? What does your code need to do?

```
create a new empty dictionary to store words {word: count}
open the file
work through each line (word) in the file
    if the word is already in the dictionary
        increment count by one
    if not
        add to dictionary with count 1
```

Then you can easily get the number of words

```
len(dictionary)
```

and the `n` most common words with their counts

```
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:n]
```