# Iterate through two strings, returning the count when characters at the same index match

Tags: python

I have two words, one is a user input string, the other is a randomly selected word from text file. I would like to return the count values that are equal in both stings and share the same string index. e.g word1 = 'bleed', word2 = slice: similar = 1.

```
word1 = 'frog'
word2 = 'friend'
correct = 0

if len(word1) > len(word2):
    for i in range(len(word2)):
        if word1[i] == word2[i]:
            correct =+ 1
        else:
            correct == 0

else:
   for i in range(len(word1)):
       if word1[i] == word2[i]:
           correct =+ 1
       else:
           correct == 0
```

I'm new to programming and unfortunately My attempt maxes out at correct = 1. For the words i have used in the example frog and friend i would expect to see correct = 2, my code produces correct = 1. How do i add to correct, beyond 1? thank you

Comment: `=+` isn't `+=`, `==` doesn't actually do anything, and if you change it to `=`, it's going to do the wrong thing.

Comment: You're using the operator `+=` incorrectly. Your code always make correct receive `+1` instead of incrementing.

Comment: Instead of range-len iteration, just use `zip`. It automatically stops at the end of the shortest input sequence, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Definitely look into the zip() built-in function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is much easier with `zip()` and the `filter()` built in function:

*Python 2.x*:

```
In [23]: word1 = 'frog'
In [24]: word2 = 'friend'
In [25]: print len(filter(lambda (x, y): x == y, zip(word1, word2)))
2
```

*Python 3.x* (see comments for pointers re: changes):

```
>>> word1 = 'frog'
>>> word2 = 'friend'
>>> len(list(filter(lambda xy: xy[0] == xy[1], zip(word1, word2))))
2
```

**Update**: since you're new to programming, I'll attempt to explain this solution a bit:

Python has support for sequences (commonly thought of as an ordered list of items), such as `[1,2,3]` or `['a', 'b', 'c', 123, 456]`. However, Python treats *strings* as an ordered list of characters as well, so `'hello world'` is also a list. As a result, you may apply Python's list-related operators/built-in functions on strings as well. Therefore your problem reduces to treat `word1` and `word2` as lists and find indexes on these lists where their items match.

So let's use Python's special functions for this.`zip` is a nifty function that takes more than one sequence, and makes a new list with each item at index X made up of the values at index X in each of the input sequences. For instance, `zip([1,2], [3,4])` becomes `[(1,3), (2,4)]` and `zip('foo', 'bar')` becomes `[('f', 'b'), ('o', 'a'), ('o', 'r')]`. This last result is very useful for your problem -- now you just need to run a function through each tuple (i.e. a value of the form `(x,y)`) through a function to check if the values are equal. You could do that in a loop as in other languages, but you can also make Python do the looping for you and provide just a function that returns the result of applying equality to each tuple on a list by using a function such as `filter()` or `map()`. In your case, you want `filter()` which runs through the input list and includes every value in the original list that causes the value of a passed in function (the `lambda` in the solution) to be `True`. The length of the "filtered" list is essentially the number of matches.

Hope this helps. Note that if you are new to Python, you will want to look up list/sequences, tuples, zip, filter, and lambda in a good book or the [official Python reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) to fully understand the solution.

Oh, and welcome to programming :-)

Comment: thank you for your time, I really appreciate your extensive answer! I tried to put this to use, and got the error 'invalid syntax' with the opening parenthesis after lambda highlighted. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Hmm, looks like a difference between Python 2.7 which I ran this on, and Python 3 which does give the error you indicate. Not sure what syntax has changed -- let me dig in. Do you happen to have Python 2 installed on your machine? For me on Ubuntu, that's just 'python'.

Comment: Ok, here's the problem: tuple auto-unpacking changed in Python 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712210/python-3-2-lambda-syntax-error. Still seeing an error with the print statement, and filter now returns an iterable but not a straight up list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319025/filters-in-python. I'll update the answer with the correct Python 3 equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Using `zip` and for comprehension:

```
word1 = 'frog'
word2 = 'friend'

sum([1 for (l,r) in zip(word1, word2) if l == r])
```

Comment: No need for the inner list, you also don't need the `1` simply: `sum(l == r for l,r in zip('frog','friend'))`

Answer (score 2):

example for 'reduce' .

```
>>> word1 = 'frog'
>>> word2 = 'friend'
>>> reduce(lambda z,(x,y): (z+1) if x == y else z, zip(word1,word2), 0)
2
```

---

reduce take 3 arguments,

- function called with accumulator and each item of the list.
- list.
- initial value of accumulator.

Accumulator looks like temporary variable. But the value of the accumulator is taken over.

In my code:

function is    `The value of the accumulator is taken over.`
list is `zip(word1, word2)` so `[('f', 'f'), ('r', 'r'), ('o', 'i'), ('g', 'e')]`
initial value is 0

Let's see how reduce works.

First time, function called with arguments `z := 0, (x,y) := ('f', 'f')` and return 1,
because `x == y` is True and `z + 1` is 1.

Next time, function called with arguments `z := 1, (x,y) := ('r', 'r')`.
`z` is 1, that is point, please remember accumulator is taken over. so `z` is last result.
In this time, `x == y` is True, too. function return 2 (`z + 1`).

Next time, called with `2, ('o', 'i')` returns `2`. ( 'o' is not 'i' ).

And last, called with `2, ('g', 'e')` returns `2`.

That's all, result was 2.

Answer (score 1):

As user2347112 stated in comments, this task can be easily done with `zip()` built-in funciton:

```
word1 = 'frog'
word2 = 'friend'
correct = 0

for i,j in zip(word1,word2):
    if i == j:
        correct+=1

print(correct)
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, `=+` needs to be `+=` to properly increment `correct`, and get rid of your `else` clauses as they do nothing.

As mentioned in the comments you should look into [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
In [1]: word1 = 'frog'

In [2]: word2 = 'friend'

In [3]: sum(1 for a, b in zip(word1, word2) if a == b)
Out[3]: 2
```

Comment: You can replace the `1` with your if statement directly, like this: `sum(a == b for a,b in zip('frog','friend'))`