# Printing mapped items in reverse order

Tags: python

Given a map of simple integers:

```
this_map = map(int, input().split())
2 4 1 3 5
```

How do I print `this_map` in reverse order? I can print each item with a simple for loop but printing the thing in reverse format requires indexing and this is not possible through standard procedure.

```
for item in this_map[::-1]:
    print(item)

TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481061/can-i-use-index-information-inside-the-map-function) on using `enumerate()` exists but how do I use it here to add indexes?

**Note**: I'm using Python 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example didn't work because `map()` behaves differently in Python 2 vs Python 3.  In Python 2 it returns a list, but in Python 3 it returns a special `map` object.

You can convert it to a list by calling `list()` on it:

```
this_map = list(this_map)
```

Comment: This is the only way for a map.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
this_map = map(int, reversed("2 4 1 3 5".split()))
for item in this_map:
    print(item)
```

Comment: @Shiv_90, cannot use with map, so you would have to work over the input split.

Comment: Thanks for the highlight. `reversed()` works as you just described above. Gordon's answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
for i in reversed(this_map):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the `map` into a `list` first

```
this_map = list(map(int, input().split()))
for item in this_map[::-1]:
    print(item)
```