# Invalid syntax in opening functions module

Tags: python

When I am running my code, a syntax error take place and I don't know why.Of course I installed the Functions module successfully, but this error take place.

```
%pylab inline
%matplotlib notebook

rcParams["figure.figsize"]=12,8
from functions import circles,deposit_particles,create_envelope,create_envelope_selected
from ipywidgets import interact
from ipywidgets.widgets import IntSlider,IntText,Label,VBox,HBox,Layout,Button,FloatSlider,ToggleButton,FloatText
from IPython.display import clear_output,display
'''

the error:
'''
Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Win 8.1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-3-1f3efd9a314f>", line 10, in <module>
    from functions import circles,deposit_particles,create_envelope,create_envelope_selected

  File "C:\Users\Win 8.1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\functions.py", line 68
    nodes = tuple(map(lambda (k, v): process_node(inner, k, v),
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712210/python-3-2-lambda-syntax-error. This syntax is invalid since Python 3.

Comment: this error return to the "from functions import" that it may be have problem in importing?

Answer (score 0):

just patch functions.py: change all lambda (x, y)    ->     lambda x, y

as from https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/6030

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30908319)